# gulp-merge-json: Disregards Input Files?

Tags: javascript, json, file-io, gruntjs, gulp

Here's the situation: I'm trying to merge 2,089 JSON files into a single JSON file. They are all located in a directory called 'lenders'.

I've tried a couple Python scripts, but now I want to use the gulp module named gulp-merge-json (it's been recommended more than once now).

I run the gulp task, and the load time suggests it's truly processing all 2,000+ files (compared to my test on just 3, which worked); but my resulting file only contains JSON data from a single file. Odder still (maybe a hint towards a solution) is that the file being used was titled 999.json. These files are all named x.json, where 1 < x < 2,090.

I don't see anything that stands out in the data to cause this error. File 999 does not seem exceptional in any other way, other than it has obviously the highest summative title value.

Enough; here is the code:

```
gulp.src('/Users/me/Documents/lenders/*.json')
.pipe(merge('combined.json'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('/Users/me/Documents/LendersData'));
```

Put this in a gulpfile with all the right installed dependencies and it does run. Simply put, this process (supposedly) takes all of the files in the lenders directory using a json-indicated glob, creates a directory called LendersData, and puts the combined.json file inside it.

Does anyone have experience with this gulp module? I'm at a loss why it take a believable amount of time to run the task judging by the amount of input data I fed it (somewhere in the gigabyte range), then leaves me with only the data from 999.json. Thank you!

**EDIT:** My test with 3 JSON files did not work. The only file out of 1.json, 2.json and 3.json that was written to the output file was 3.json. Now, this is an indicator that only the last file read by the script is copied over. In the case of 999.json for the full attempt, that could be the last file listed if they are sorted in a certain way. I thought my glob was going to handle every single file in the directory?

Here is an example of **what I mean by merging** the two. Suppose we have two files, 1.json and 2.json;

1.json:

```
{
    "header":{
        "total":2,"page":1,"date":"2016-08-01T17:29:57Z","page_size":1},
  "lenders": [
      {"lender_id":"matt","name":"Matt"}
  ]
}
```

And 2.json:

```
{
    "header":{
        "total":2,"page":2,"date":"2016-08-01T17:30:57Z","page_size":1},
  "lenders": [
      {"lender_id":"sarah","name":"Sarah"}
  ]
}
```

The merge result:

```
{
  "lenders": [
      {"lender_id":"matt","name":"Matt"},
      {"lender_id:"sarah","name":"Sarah"}
  ]
}
```

(I realize popping the header is an additional requirement, but not doing so leads to invalid JSON)

Comment: I just tested it now and it works fine for me (or at least how I expected it to). Although I'm not sure what output you want. What exactly do you mean by "merge"? That gulp plugin overwrites matching keys. For example, if you have two JSON files, the first containing `{"value": 1}`, the second containing `{"value": 2}`, the output of merging them will be just `{"value": 2}` (since the second replaces the common key `value`). Therefore if all of your JSON input files have _exactly_ the  same keys you should expect the output to be just the same as the last file.

Comment: If you could post an example of `1.json` and `2.json` and the expected output it should be clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks MadScone, that explains a lot. So the last file read is 999.json, which has the final say in the output data.

What I meant by merge is create a file which holds all of the 1.json as well as the 2.json as a single, valid JSON file.

I realize there may be further editing to do, such as popping extraneous headers. But if I merge 2,089 json files, I mean I want all of their individual data collated into a single source. I have more in mind to do with this single file (make it into a SQL file). 

Thanks for the response!

Comment: I posted an answer below based on what I think you might want. I'm assuming you want to create a JSON array output.

Comment: Sorry I had posted a solution before your edit with examples, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on your last update. This should do it:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var combine = require('gulp-jsoncombine');

function combineFiles (files) {

    var lenders = [];
    for (var file in files) {
      if (files.hasOwnProperty(file) && files[file].hasOwnProperty('lenders')) {
        lenders.push(files[file].lenders);
      }
    }

    var result = {lenders: [].concat.apply([], lenders)};
    return new Buffer(JSON.stringify(result));
}

gulp.task('default', function () {

    return gulp.src('lenders/*.json')
        .pipe(combine('combined.json', combineFiles))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('LendersData'));

});
```